# problem in imported address

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info, buy-bitcoins

I have $10 at my address. I only imported that address in my other wallet, but it shows the balance of $0 and no past transactions.
I tried my balance address of $18 and the same zero balance is shown at the imported address not even any past transaction 
I even put my private key that does not show any amount
What is the problem? Can someone help with this?

Comment: have you got the public address ready to hand? if so look it up on a block explorer to verify the btc is actually at the address. Secondly verify it is btc and not bitcoin cash address

Comment: What wallet software are you using?

Comment: blockchain wallet

Comment: Could you resolve your issue? You mean blockchain.info? Have you imported the addresses using the private key? Check out https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/articles/210353823-How-do-I-manage-Imported-Addresses-